# Normed space inequality

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I have this inequality for elements $x,y$ in a Normed space. How do I deduce from this that $\frac{4}{5}||x||\leqslant y\leqslant \frac{6}{5}||x||$

[image]
I have tried to use the triangle inequality but I’m getting the negative of the result I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have\begin{align}\|y\|&=\|y-x+x\|\\&\leqslant\|y-x\|+\|x\|\\&<\frac65\|x\|\end{align}and\begin{align}\|y\|&=\|y-x+x\|\\&\geqslant\bigl|\|y-x\|-\|x\|\bigr|\\&=\|x\|-\|y-x\|,\end{align}since $\|x\|\geqslant\|y-x\|$. But $\|x\|-\|x-y\|>\frac45\|x\|$.

Comment: Is that reverse triangle inequality?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Where does $||x||\geqslant ||y-x||$ come from?

Comment: From the fact that $\|y-x\|=\|x-y\|<\frac15\|x\|<\|x\|$.